# How to map the keyboard to type Lower than or Greater than symbol on thinkpad T430 keyboard?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

I have a thinkpad T430 with an azerty keyboard running endeavourOS:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/ywFzZMz]

Unfortunately, I can't type the "lower than" and "greater than" symbols.
I was hoping that it should be possible to remap some keys (possibly Alt+w and Alt+x) to type these symbols.

Up to now I haven't been successful. I installed keymapper, wrote a keymapper.conf with:

```
# define some more aliases
  Alt   = AltLeft
  AltGr = AltRight
  Win   = Meta

# Mapping on thinkpad T430 azerty keyboard

Alt{W} >> !Alt IntlBackslash
Alt{X} >> !Alt Shift{IntlBackslash}
```

then from a console:

```
$ systemctl start keymapperd
[jeanpat@T430 ~]$ keymapper
```

with no effect...

I also tried:
[image: key mapper screenshot]

No more success.
Any idea to fix this. Any idea to fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Which language are you using? Maybe you can use the `onboard` screen keyboard (if not for permanent use, at least while testing and exploring, because you might find some already existing key combination for < and > )?

Comment: French. I'm afraid that onboard will be not that convenient, I can use the character app to copy paste.

Comment: I meant that you can use `onboard` to check if any of the 'alt' characters and 'alt gr' characters are already your < and > characters. You get a quick overview that way instead of typing them one at a time. You could also check rather easily if some special French keyboard, for example Canadian, has those characters.

Answer (score 0):

I found the `<` and `>` keys on the French keyboard via `setxkbmap fr` and `onboard` in my 'normal separate keyboard', and I think and hope that you will find it on the same keys combinations on your Thinkpad T430 keyboard.

[image]

Press **<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>** (the right Alt) key and the (left) **<kbd>shift</kbd>** key, and you will get the following keys,

[image]

- **`<`** is on the Z key
- **`>`** is on the X key

Comment: Thank you,     

altgraph+left shift + Z yields:  <


But 

     altgraph+left shift + x yields a weird : ›

Comment: @Jean-Pat, Thanks for the feed-back. I have no keyboard like yours, so it is difficult to test different versions. Maybe you can try [*standard* French keyboard and] some special French keyboard, for example Canadian, in the search for a convenient way to print that character. An alternative is to ask (the same question as here) at **https://discourse.ubuntu.com/** and/or at some **Lenovo forum**.